# Should a singer songwriter play chord voicings outside their vocal range?

Tags: guitar, voice, vocal-range, pa

I've always understood in a band setup you want to avoid everyone fighting over the same frequency range.

But the common guitar chord voicings mean you are playing notes in the range E2-G4 which covers pretty much the entire male vocal range and a lot of the female tessitura.

Does this mean a singer songwriter type performer should seek to find chord voicings that don't overlap the vocal melody in order to keep the vocal crisper in the mix? I rarely see this happen so do different rules apply here?

Answer (score 2):

Guitar and voice are generally so tonally different it isn't really an issue. It depends a bit on playing style and guitar sound as well.

I think for any singer songwriter an awareness of space is important. Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbD7lfrsY2s) out. Note that the guitar is well back in the mix, and he is often playing fills to his own vocal. This mirrors what good arrangers do - leave space for the vocal. Space is not only in frequency domain - it is also in the time domain.